# How can I select all elements except last

Tags: css

```
                <form class="fin-search-input" method="post" action="../FinServlet">
                    <li><BR><input type="text" name="ticker" placeholder="Ticker*"></li>
                    <li><input type="text" name="fromDate" placeholder="From" id="fromDate"></li>
                    <li><input type="text" name="toDate" placeholder="To" id="toDate"></li>
                    <li><input type="submit" value="search" class="submitButton"></li>
                </form>
```

How can I select all input elements except last?
This is what I tried :

```
.fin-search-input input:not(:last-of-type){
    height:13px !important;
    width:90%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 2px #888;
    box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 2px #888;
  }
```

This css is not applied to any input element.

Comment: This is not your real code, because the code you've given should work as expected. Please show us your real code.

Comment: @BoltClock I also pointed this out

Comment: my code with last-of-type.. still didnt worked

Comment: .fin-search-input input[type=text] this worked in my scenario.

Comment: @user2536373 which browser are you using?

Comment: i tested on firefox 22.0 and chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector seems to be wrong, in the case of your posted HTML *every* `input` is the `:last-of-type` within its parent element. You need to select the `input` contained within the `:last-of-type` `li` element instead (I assume):

```
.fin-search-input li:not(:last-of-type) input {
    /* css */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ra3ax/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
.fclass input:not(:last-of-type) { color:red }
```

Answer (score 0):

`:last-child` selector should work. I have checked it. Use last-of-type instead. The `:last-of-type` selector matches every element that is the last child, of a particular type, of its parent.

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qFN4w/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your current code works.

`:last-child` can be used this way with `:not`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbryf/)**